# Is it worth throwing an error when override the equals(Object obj) method if the types are not equal

Tags: oop, equality

In OOP, is it worth throwing an error when override the `equals(Object obj)` method if the types are not equal?
I want to prevent comparison of non-comparable types.

*Problem*
For example, i create like ValueObject - StudentAge, StudentId classes.
I write checking that the user grading the student has a different id from himself, can be written incorrectly, if the programmer accidentally gets information about his age from the data of the current user, and not the identifier - while the compiler will not generate an error.

```java
// Mistake
if(!id.equals(student.getAge()){
// …
}
```

```java
// Right
if(!id.equals(student.getId()){
// …
}
```

And such typos happen often, and may not be noticed even during code review.
I want to prevent this throw exception for non-comparable types, but *almost* all examples that i

Answer (score 0):

To obtain what you're willing, you just have, each time you are defining the equals method of a specific object (`Student`, `StudentAge`, `StudentId`...), to check for their instance classes.
And, in your case, to be vehement when it isn't what you're expecting.

For `StudentAge`, for example:

```java
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o instanceof StudentAge == false) {
      throw ... your Exception ...
   }

   StudentAge candidate = (StudentAge)o
   return candidate.value == this.value;
}
```

Then by the force of things, class after class when you comes to `Student`:

```java
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o instanceof Student == false) {
      throw ... your Exception ...
   }

   Student candidate = (Student)o
   boolean equals = true;
   equals = equals && candidate.studentAge.equals(this.studentAge);
   equals = equals && candidate.studentId.equals(this.studentId);
   ...

   return equals;
}
```

Any "wrongly" typed class will throw an exception instead of only returning false, then.